# Thresholding algorithm for separating skin from clothes in python

Tags: noise, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an several images that look like the following:

[image]

I would like to separate the skin from the trousers here without specifically training a segmentation model. Can anyone suggest any such algorithm that can potentially achieve this task? Also a dummy example that can demonstrate this would be great. Thank you

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/.

Comment: Link from SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/14756351/1463143.

Answer (score 0):

Given there is no learning model which can combine spatial and color information you're left with thresholding based operations.

The tricks here are limited to the color space and the calibration tables of different methods (See [Comparative Study of Skin Color Detection and Segmentation in HSV and YCbCr Color Space](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915018918) which is available on [SciHub](https://sci-hub.st/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915018918)).

Now you can combine several approaches either with `OR` to increase the recall or `AND` to increase the precision.

I'd choose the `AND` path and then add another step for segmentation which is similar to [A Closed Form Solution to Natural Image Matting](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4359322) to fine tune the skin mask.